# Can I reference a flow variable in a custom lighting component placed on a flow screen?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, custom, screen-flow

Is it possible to reference flow data in a custom lightning component placed on a flow screen?

Basically I have a component that is executing methods that require data that is gathered earlier in the flow

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, your component needs to implement `lightning:availableForFlowScreens` , the variable name in flow should match the attribute name in your lightning aura component.

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="greeting" type="String" access="global" />
    <aura:attribute name="subject" type="String" access="global" />

    <div style="box">
      <span class="greeting">{!v.greeting}</span>, {!v.subject}!
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Here you also need to create flow variable of same name , greeting and subject.

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_screens.htm?search_text=flow

https://cloudanswers.com/how-to-use-lightning-components-in-flows/

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! I tried creating an aura attribute with the same name on my component, but unfortunately I was unable to get the value stored in the flow to appear on my component. Is there something that I may have missed?